# Approach to User Profile craetion with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I have created a sample blog site to work with that stores user information in separate tables based on the type of information.

For instance CustomerGeneral table would contain all user's username, password, and ID(primary key) values.

CustomerContact table would contain email, address, contactId(primary key) and ID(foreign key) values.

and lastly the CustomerPicInfo table which contains picId(primary key), ID(foreign key),  picInfo and picPath values.

Ive seen approaches where each user has their own table instead but have never seen a proper demonstration of it to learn more. I am curious of what method professional php developers go about with the creation of their user and perhaps in a little bit of detail the method that is took to do so. Also if there is something wrong with my approach, i would like just a summary of my fault so that I can further perfect it.

Comment: One table per user ? Make no sense, why do this ? It's like if you have an eCommerce, will you build a db with one table per product ? Nop...

Comment: Its the technique i had learnt from O'reilly "Learning php, Mysql & javascript" by robin Nixon. Ive used that book as my go to and thats the the only way of creation i had read.